# Error creating AWS CloudFormation stack : Cannot restore this instance based in Windows OS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, aws-cloudformation

I am using the following Cloudformation Json to create a new Sql Server RDS instance of more storage from an existing snapshot. THe Json is valid and i am able to initiate the stack creation. Its failing with the error

"Cannot restore this instance based in Windows OS because the request has a different storage type than the backup". What does this mean ? Am i missing any thing ?

```
{
    "AWSTemplateFormatVersion" : "2010-09-09",
    "Resources" : {
        "DBInstance" : {
            "Type": "AWS::RDS::DBInstance",
            "Properties": {
                "DBInstanceClass" : "db.m2.xlarge", 
                "AllocatedStorage" : "400", 
                "MasterUsername" : "myusername", 
                "MasterUserPassword" : "mypassword", 
                "DBSnapshotIdentifier":"xxxxxxxx-2016-07-13-17-00" 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the SQL Server Express edition or something different?

Comment: Its not SQl server Express, Its Sql server standard edition. Im pretty sure it gets all that info from the DBSnapshotIdentifier

Comment: What are the specification for this snapshot xxxxxxxx-2016-07-13-17-00 what is the storagee type instance type.

Comment: Storage type is : General Purpose (SSD), i dont know where can i get the information for Instance type. As far as i know it should be sqlserver-se

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Missed Iops, This is working now

```
{
    "AWSTemplateFormatVersion" : "2010-09-09",  
    "Resources" : {
        "MyDB" : {
            "Type": "AWS::RDS::DBInstance",
            "Properties": {             
                "DBInstanceClass"       : "db.t2.medium",
                "AllocatedStorage"      : "400",
                "MasterUsername"        : "xxxxxxxxxxxx",
                "MasterUserPassword"    : "xxxxxxxxxxxx",
                "DBSnapshotIdentifier"  : "xxxxxxxxxxxx-2016-07-13-1700",
                "Iops":"2000",
                "StorageType":"io1"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

(year later, in case future googlers)
Had the same issue, however I missed `"StorageType"` (I see OP also missed it and probably added it at the same time as Iops). `"StorageType"` defaults to `"standard"` (i.e. magnetic) when using CloudFormation, however defaults to `"gp2"` (SSD) when using the console. 
Therefore a backup created from a console created DB is likely to be using SSD, but the instance generated in CF is using Magnetic, unless `"StorageType"` is declared as `"gp2"`.